# Yii, radioButtonList disabling OR enabling dropDownList

Tags: jquery, yii, radiobuttonlist

So I have this radiobutton with 2 options, `Package` and `Service`

How can I enable or disable the respective dropDownList when the radiobutton is clicked.

I have this:

```
<?php echo $form->radioButtonList($model, 'option', array('0'=>'Packaged Services', '1'=>'Individual Services'), array( 
        'labelOptions'=>array('style'=>'display:inline'),
        'separator' => " | ",
        )
);
```

And my JQuery:

```
function disableBox(){
    if ($('#Booking_option') == '0'){
        $('#Booking_clientPackagedservice_id').prop('disable', false);
        $('#Booking_service_id').prop('disable', true);         
    }
    else if ($('#Booking_option') == '1'){
        $('#Booking_clientPackagedservice_id').prop('disable', true);
        $('#Booking_service_id').prop('disable', false);            
    }
}
```

How can I call the function `disableBox` in the `radioButtonList`? 
Please advise. Thanks

Comment: what is your html output for the radibuttonlist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't related to yii realy. It's completely a javascript question and therefore has javascript based solutions. However, I think you should have an event handler for clicking on `radiobutton`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
        if(this.value == /* something */)
           disableBox();
        else
          //function for enabling dropDownList 
    });
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You mean this? :

```
$(document).on('change', 'option:selected', function(){
   if($(this).index() == 0)
       disableBox();
   else
       enableBox();
})
```